# how to display a floating figure in a GUI axes handle

Tags: matlab, matlab-guide

I would like to diplay the current time in my GUI in Matlab, I would like to use the tutorial (GUI_17) in this [link](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/24861-41-complete-gui-examples) to produce the watch (or something similar). The code is like the following:

```
    function [] = GUI_17()
    % Demonstrate how to have a running clock in a GUI, and timer use.
    % Creates a small little GUI which displays the correct time and is updated
    % every minute according to the system clock.
    %
    % Author:  Matt Fig
    % Date:  1/15/2010



    S.fh = figure('units','pixels',...
                  'position',[300 300 180 50],...
                  'menubar','none',...
                  'name','GUI_17',...
                  'numbertitle','off',...
                  'resize','off');
    S.tx = uicontrol('style','text',...
                     'unit','pix',...
                     'position',[35 10 110 30],...
                     'string',datestr(now,16),...
                     'backgroundc',get(S.fh,'color'),...
                     'fontsize',18,...
                     'fontweight','bold',...
                     'foregroundcolor',[.9 .1 .1]);
    STRT = 60 - str2double(datestr(now,'ss')); % So we can update every minute.             
    tmr = timer('Name','Reminder',...
                'Period',60,...  % Update the time every 60 seconds.
                'StartDelay',STRT,... % In seconds.
                'TasksToExecute',inf,...  % number of times to update
                'ExecutionMode','fixedSpacing',...
                'TimerFcn',{@updater}); 
    start(tmr);  % Start the timer object.
    set(S.fh,'deletefcn',{@deleter})  % Kill timer if fig is closed.

        function [] = updater(varargin)
        % timerfcn for the timer.  If figure is deleted, so is timer.
             % I use a try-catch here because timers are finicky in my
             % experience.
             try
                 set(S.tx,'string',datestr(now,16))
                 if ~str2double(datestr(now,'MM'))
                     X = load('gong');  % At the hour, sound a gong.
                     sound(X.y,X.Fs*2.5)  
                 end
                 clear X
             catch
                 delete(S.fh) % Close it all down.
             end
        end

        function [] = deleter(varargin)
        % If figure is deleted, so is timer.
             stop(tmr);
             delete(tmr);
        end
    end
```

I created my own GUI using GUIDE and created an empty axes1, which I wanted to to use as a replacement to the figure definition in the original clock function. I copied the whole function from the link and added it to the bottom of my GUIDE program. This is my attempt to replace the figure handle of the function:

```
 % S.fh = figure('units','pixels',...
%               'position',[300 300 180 50],...
 %               'menubar','none',...
 %               'name','GUI_17',...
 %               'numbertitle','off',...
 %               'resize','off');
```

by the following:

```
    S.fh=handles.axes1;
```

But it doesn't show any output in the frame, what is the right way to do it?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to exactly replicate the GUI of the tutorial using the `GUIDE` tool, first you have to notice that in the tutoirial the clock is created by using a `text` uicontrol, so it is clear why you've inserted in the GUI an `axes`.

Also. the GUI "window" (the `figure`) is automatically created by GUIDE, so there is not needed to add ax axes, unless you want to create an "analog" clock with hands for the hours, minutes, etc, but, in this case, the GUI will result more complicated.

Working with `GUIDE` you have to simply add a `text uicontrol`, then, if you want to exactly reproduce the shape of the clock in the tutorial, you can set the different parameters of the `figure` and of the `text` uicontrol through the `Property Inspector`.

Once you have created the GUI, you can insert in its `.m` file the function from the tutorial, in order to make it working, as follows:

- Insert the code for the creation of the timer and its initialization in the GUI `OpeningFcn`
- Use the figure's `handles` to share the variables among the `figure uicontrols`
- Add the figure's handels as additional input parameter of the `updater` and `deleter` function

Then you can just copy & paste the `updater` and `deleter` functions, the third element of the `varargin` cellarray will be the figure's handle struct in which you have set, in   the `OpeningFcn` the `timer` data.

With respect to the code in the tutorial, in the `updater` function you have to add the line:

```
fig_handles=varargin{3}
```

to retrieve the handle of the `text` uicontrol.

The whole GUI, created with GUIDE, will look like as folloes (the comments in the code should highlight the relevant modification above described):

```
function varargout = GUI_1_GUIDE(varargin)
% GUI_1_GUIDE MATLAB code for GUI_1_GUIDE.fig
%      GUI_1_GUIDE, by itself, creates a new GUI_1_GUIDE or raises the existing
%      singleton*.
%
%      H = GUI_1_GUIDE returns the handle to a new GUI_1_GUIDE or the handle to
%      the existing singleton*.
%
%      GUI_1_GUIDE('CALLBACK',hObject,eventData,handles,...) calls the local
%      function named CALLBACK in GUI_1_GUIDE.M with the given input arguments.
%
%      GUI_1_GUIDE('Property','Value',...) creates a new GUI_1_GUIDE or raises the
%      existing singleton*.  Starting from the left, property value pairs are
%      applied to the GUI before GUI_1_GUIDE_OpeningFcn gets called.  An
%      unrecognized property name or invalid value makes property application
%      stop.  All inputs are passed to GUI_1_GUIDE_OpeningFcn via varargin.
%
%      *See GUI Options on GUIDE's Tools menu.  Choose "GUI allows only one
%      instance to run (singleton)".
%
% See also: GUIDE, GUIDATA, GUIHANDLES

% Edit the above text to modify the response to help GUI_1_GUIDE

% Last Modified by GUIDE v2.5 16-Aug-2018 18:29:37

% Begin initialization code - DO NOT EDIT
gui_Singleton = 1;
gui_State = struct('gui_Name',       mfilename, ...
   'gui_Singleton',  gui_Singleton, ...
   'gui_OpeningFcn', @GUI_1_GUIDE_OpeningFcn, ...
   'gui_OutputFcn',  @GUI_1_GUIDE_OutputFcn, ...
   'gui_LayoutFcn',  [] , ...
   'gui_Callback',   []);
if nargin && ischar(varargin{1})
   gui_State.gui_Callback = str2func(varargin{1});
end

if nargout
   [varargout{1:nargout}] = gui_mainfcn(gui_State, varargin{:});
else
   gui_mainfcn(gui_State, varargin{:});
end
% End initialization code - DO NOT EDIT


% --- Executes just before GUI_1_GUIDE is made visible.
function GUI_1_GUIDE_OpeningFcn(hObject, eventdata, handles, varargin)
% This function has no output args, see OutputFcn.
% hObject    handle to figure
% eventdata  reserved - to be defined in a future version of MATLAB
% handles    structure with handles and user data (see GUIDATA)
% varargin   command line arguments to GUI_1_GUIDE (see VARARGIN)

% Choose default command line output for GUI_1_GUIDE
handles.output = hObject;

%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%
% Insert here the code for the creation of the timer and its initialization
% Use the figure's handles to share the variables among the figure
% uicontrols
%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%
handles.text_clock.String=datestr(now,16);
handles.STRT = 60 - str2double(datestr(now,'ss')); % So we can update every minute.
handles.tmr = timer('Name','Reminder',...
   'Period',60,...  % Update the time every 60 seconds.
   'StartDelay',handles.STRT,... % In seconds.
   'TasksToExecute',inf,...  % number of times to update
   'ExecutionMode','fixedSpacing')

set(handles.tmr,'TimerFcn',{@updater handles});
%
% Add the figure's handels as additional input parameter of the "updater"
% and "deleter" function
%
set(hObject,'deletefcn',{@deleter handles})  % Kill timer if fig is closed.
start(handles.tmr);  % Start the timer object.
%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%

% Update handles structure
guidata(hObject, handles);

% UIWAIT makes GUI_1_GUIDE wait for user response (see UIRESUME)
% uiwait(handles.figure1);

%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%
% Add the "updater" and "deleter" function
% The third element of the "varargin" parameter is the figure's handle
% struct
%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%
function [] = updater(varargin)
% timerfcn for the timer.  If figure is deleted, so is timer.
% I use a try-catch here because timers are finicky in my
% experience.
%
fig_handles=varargin{3}
try
   set(fig_handles.text_clock,'string',datestr(now,16))
   if ~str2double(datestr(now,'MM'))
      X = load('gong');  % At the hour, sound a gong.
      sound(X.y,X.Fs*2.5)
   end
   clear X
catch
   delete(fig_handles.figure1) % Close it all down.
end

function [] = deleter(varargin)
% If figure is deleted, so is timer.
fig_handles=varargin{3}
stop(fig_handles.tmr);
delete(fig_handles.tmr);


% --- Outputs from this function are returned to the command line.
function varargout = GUI_1_GUIDE_OutputFcn(hObject, eventdata, handles)
% varargout  cell array for returning output args (see VARARGOUT);
% hObject    handle to figure
% eventdata  reserved - to be defined in a future version of MATLAB
% handles    structure with handles and user data (see GUIDATA)

% Get default command line output from handles structure
varargout{1} = handles.output;
```

Comment: Thank you very much that was very helpful, I've followed your instructions and it worked, thanks again and you answer was accepted!